# Create dynamic block in terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, hcl, terragrunt

I wanted to create `google_compute_health_check` in terraform and I'm thinking about how to make them the most versatile. My code atm looks like that

`application.hcl`

```sh
inputs = {
  health_checks = {
    tcp-health-check = {
      name                = "tcp-health-check"
      desc                = "Health check via tcp"
      port                = 80
      timeout_sec         = 4
      check_interval_sec  = 30
    }
  }
```

main `terragrunt.hcl`

```sh
include {
  path = find_in_parent_folders()
}

terraform { source ...}

locals {
  app_vars    = read_terragrunt_config(find_in_parent_folders("application.hcl"))
}

inputs = {
  # and my idea was that every invocation of the module, picks it's own set
  # of health checks that it wants to use
  health_checks = [local.app_vars.inputs.health_checks.tcp-health-check]
}
```

now the module `main.tf` looks like so

```sh
locals {
  checks = { for check in var.health_checks: check.name => check }
}

resource "google_compute_health_check" "main" {
  for_each           = local.checks
  name               = each.value.name

  timeout_sec        = each.value.timeout_sec
  check_interval_sec = each.value.check_interval_sec

  dynamic tcp_health_check {
    #for_each             = each.value.name == "tcp_health_check" ? each.value : []
    #for_each             = lookup(each.value, "tcp_health_check", [])
    for_each             = contains(keys(each.value), "tcp_health_check") != null ? each.value : {}
      content {
        port               = 80
        #        port               = each.value.port
        #        port_name          = each.value.name
      }
  }
```

and I'm stuck in the dynamic block - how to make it work so that it only is applied when I pass the `tcp` health_check, and when I pass, `ssh` it creates dynamic `ssh` block (I know there is no ssh block in the code atm, but in future I'll expand the module by whichever healht-check I'll need)

---

The errors I get are as followed with `contains`

```sh
Error: List longer than MaxItems

  on main.tf line 30, in resource "google_compute_health_check" "main":
  30: resource "google_compute_health_check" "main" {

Attribute supports 1 item maximum, config has 7 declared

ERRO[0011] 1 error occurred:
    * exit status 1
```

with `lookup`

```sh
Error: ExactlyOne

  on main.tf line 30, in resource "google_compute_health_check" "main":
  30: resource "google_compute_health_check" "main" {

"ssl_health_check": one of
`grpc_health_check,http2_health_check,http_health_check,https_health_check,ssl_health_check,tcp_health_check`
must be specified

ERRO[0005] 1 error occurred:
    * exit status 1
```

and with `==` comparison

```sh
Error: Inconsistent conditional result types

  on main.tf line 44, in resource "google_compute_health_check" "main":
  44:     for_each             = each.value.name == "tcp_health_check" ? each.value : []
    |----------------
    | each.value is object with 7 attributes
    | each.value.name is "tcp-health-check"

The true and false result expressions must have consistent types. The given
expressions are object and tuple, respectively.

ERRO[0005] 1 error occurred:
    * exit status 1
```

---

Ok solved it doing it the other way, but thanks for the answer Marcin

`terragrunt.hcl`

```sh
  inputs = {
    name                = "nat-health-check"
    used_for            = "used for NATs"
    check_interval_sec  = 30
    timeout_sec         = 5
    healthy_threshold   = 1
    unhealthy_threshold = 5
    http_checks         = local.app_vars.inputs.health_checks.nat-http
  }
```

and modules `main.tf`

```sh
resource "google_compute_health_check" "main" {
  name               = var.name
  timeout_sec        = var.timeout_sec
  check_interval_sec = var.check_interval_sec
  description        = "${var.name} - ${var.used_for}"

  dynamic "http_health_check" {
    for_each = var.http_checks != null ? [1] : []
    content {
      port               = var.http_checks.port
      request_path       = var.http_checks.request_path
      port_specification = var.http_checks.port_specification
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with your current code? Any errors?

Comment: I've put them in the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following

```
contains(keys(each.value), "tcp_health_check") != null ? each.value : {}
```

fails because when this is true, your dynamic block `tcp_health_check` will be executed **more then once**, since your `each.value` is just a map of values. You can't have more then one `tcp_health_check` block.

The second

```
for_each             = lookup(each.value, "tcp_health_check", [])
```

does not fail and is correct. But since it results in `false`, your  `tcp_health_check` block is not created. This fails as you are not providing any of the alternative blocks `grpc_health_check,http2_health_check,http_health_check,https_health_check,ssl_health_check,tcp_health_check`.

The last attempt:

```
for_each             = each.value.name == "tcp_health_check" ? each.value : []
```

fails because it should be `for_each             = each.value.name == "tcp_health_check" ? each.value : {}`. But if you fix this issue, `each.value` will again fail as before.

To sum up, you are always doomed fot fail, since when you eliminate your block `tcp_health_check` as in the second case, you are not providing any alternatives to it. And if your condition is `true`, `each.value` will try to create multiple blocks.

The closes solution would be (does not account for false case, where you need to provide alternatives):

```
  dynamic tcp_health_check {
    for_each           = each.value.name == "tcp_health_check" ? [1] : []
    content {
         port          = each.value.port
         port_name     = each.value.name
      }
  }
```

Comment: it still doesn't work, throws error saying that it needs one of the main blocks (ssl/https/http/tcp) looks like the if statement in for_each is false

Comment: @CptDolphin You need to provide alternatives. You are not doing this so you will always fail.

Comment: I mean, I know i'll have to provide alternatives if I don't create tcp, but I pass (seems like) proper values and it should create it but it still doesn't go through with it hmm; ill test some more and type back - if it works for you it should for me too

Comment: @CptDolphin All your conditions return `false`. So you must provide the alternatives. If you want it `true`, change your conditons or the input variable, because `each.value.name == "tcp_health_check"` does not match your variable.

Comment: ok did it other way, not the best but works, thanks for answer!!